# How to add a new specializer to cl-defmethod apply to multiple major-modes?

Tags: generics, lisp, elisp, method-dispatch, cl-lib

How can I extend a `cl-defmethod` to match on multiple `major-mode`s?  There is a little documentation in cl-generic, but I don't understand what is going on with the generalizer macros.

As an example,

```
(cl-defgeneric my-gen-fun (arg)
  (message "%S" arg))

;; define this so it wouldn't affect other cc-derived modes, eg. java, awk, etc.
(cl-defmethod my-gen-fun (&context (major-mode c-mode c++-mode) arg)
  (message "c-%S" arg))
```

I would want `(my-gen-fun arg)` to only print "c-" in both `c-mode` and `c++-mode`, but not other cc-derived modes like `java-mode` or `awk-mode`.  How can I add a new specializer to handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&context` is like `%optional` in that it applies too all the subsequent args, so it has to come after the arguments.

But the `(major-mode <foo>-mode)` thingy does not extend to `(major-mode <foo>-mode <bar>-mode)` like you suggest (although it admittedly would be a natural extension).  So instead you have to call `cl-defmethod` twice.  If the body is large, you shoud probably put it into a separate function:

```
(defun my-gen-fun-c-body (arg)
  (message "c-%S" arg))

;; define this so it wouldn't affect other cc-derived modes, eg. java, awk, etc.
(cl-defmethod my-gen-fun (arg &context (major-mode c-mode))
   (my-gen-fun-c-body arg))
(cl-defmethod my-gen-fun (arg &context (major-mode c++-mode))
   (my-gen-fun-c-body arg))
```

I do have a local patch to `cl-generic.el` which adds the "multiple major modes" functionality you suggest, but after reviewing it I see that it's kind of a hack and introduces various corner-case problems.

Some of the corner case problems are related to the fact that CLOS does not offer something like `or` or `and` specializers like:

```
(defmethod foo ((x (or (eql 4) cons))) ...)
```

this is because it can make it "impossible" to find a sound ordering of the applicable methods (e.g.,is the above specializer more or less specific than `(x list)` or `(x (or (eql 5) cons))`?).

Comment: This doesn't actually work: emacs v28.0.50 built on 03/08/20 -- ie. it doesn't run specialized methods in c-mode/c++-mode (tried from emacs -Q)

Comment: Oh, indeed, I now see that I never pushed this change to Emacs's repository.  So you have to use two defmethods (one with `c-mode` and the other with `c++-mode`)  :-(